# Inverting a boolean in Lua

Tags: lua

Is there a more elegant way to set this boolean value?
`SetScript()` is a game API, while `"OnClick"` is its handler. What is important is the method that triggers when I click on the checkbutton.

```
local foo = true

checkbutton:SetScript("OnClick", function()
   if foo == true then foo = false
   else foo = true
   end
end)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a more elegant way ?

Simply assign the negation, unconditionally: `not foo`

This works in Lua, and in essentially every other language.

```
checkbutton:SetScript("OnClick", function()
   foo = not foo
end)
```

If we're flipping {0, 1} integers instead of booleans,
then the relevant idiom is to assign `1 - foo`.